# How do I match and kill a specific process without accidentally including unrelated processes?

Tags: linux, shell, ps, false-positive

I have two Tomcat processes, one is called `event-ws`, another is called `app-event-ws`. I sometimes need to kill `event-ws` from a shell script:

```
ps -ef | grep -w event-ws | grep -v grep
```

The above will find and kill both of them; how can I find exactly find one of them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`pgrep` / `pkill` are the best tools to use in this case, *instead* of `ps`:

```
 pgrep -x event-ws   # match by executable filename 'event-ws'; print PID
 pkill -x event-ws   # match and kill
```

Each command matches process(es) whose *executable filename* is `event-ws` *exactly* (`-x`) (irrespective of whether a directory path prefix was used when the executable was launched).

Note, however, that your `pgrep` / `pkill` implementation may limit the name to *15 characters* - both when matching and in its output.

`pgrep` simply *prints* the matching PID(s) (process ID(s)), whereas `pkill` *kills* the matching process(es).

---

If, by contrast, you need to match by a *part of the full command line*, use the `-f` option with a *regular expression*:

```
pgrep -f '/event-ws/' # match by part of the full command line; print PID and name
pkill -f '/event-ws/' # match and kill
```

If you add `-l` to the `pgrep` command, the full command line of matching process(es) is printed instead of just the process name.

Comment: Great! Thank you for your help and patient.